# Why is a constant always a stopping time?

Tags: measure-theory, stopping-times

In my book, it states that any constant, including, $\infty$, is a stopping time. But why is this? I thought the reason might be that a constant is measurable with regards to the trivial sigma-algebra, i.e. $\{\emptyset, \Omega\}$ and since $\emptyset \in \mathcal{F}_n$ the results follow? Or what is the reason?

Thanks.

Comment: We're going to need more context here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\tau=k,\,k \in \mathbb{N}\cup \{\infty\}$. Recalling the definition, $\tau$ is a $\mathscr{F}_n$-stopping time if $\{\tau\leq n\}\in \mathscr{F}_n,\,\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. Now if $k<\infty$ we have
$$\{\tau\leq n\}=\begin{cases}\Omega&n\geq k\\
\emptyset &n<k
\end{cases}\in \mathscr{F}_n,\,\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$$
while if $k=\infty$, $\{\tau\leq n\}=\emptyset$ for all $n$ so $\tau $ is always a stopping time.

Comment: Do I understand it correctly: $\{\tau \leqslant n\} = \{\tau(\omega) \leqslant n\}$ is the set of instances where the stopping time $\tau$ is less or equal than $n$? And if $k<\infty$ is $\tau < n$ always true if $n\geqslant k$ and never true if $n<k$?

Comment: @HelloWorld By definition $\{\tau \leq n\}=\{\omega: \tau(\omega) \leq n\}$. Since $\tau(\omega)=k$ for all $\omega$, we have that $\{\omega:\tau(\omega)\leq n\}=\Omega$ for all $n\geq k$ (so, always) and $\{\omega:\tau(\omega)\leq n\}=\emptyset$ for all $n<k$ (so, never).

Comment: Thanks! Yes I meant the $\{\omega...\}$ not $\{\tau(\omega)\}...$ ;)